# How to print the connection url of a JDBC?

Tags: java, database, jdbc, jta

If a JDBC database is running, eg `jdbc:hsqldb:mem:testdb` or any other non-inmemory db: how can I `System.out.println()` the URL of the database?

(I know I could look it up in persistence, I thought want to print it from code and not by reading the persistence.xml)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try call `getMetaData()` on    Connection instance that return    DatabaseMetaData that contain `getURL` method.